# Find a grammar that generates this palindrome language

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammar

This is a homework problem.  The problem is:

Find a grammar that generates this language:

L = {wcw^R: w ∈ {a,b}+ } over alphabet Σ = {a, b, c}.

I have tried many different transitions, but can't find one that creates this.  Here is the most recent one I tried that failed:

S -> Sa

S -> Sb

S^R -> aS^R

S^R -> bS^R

S -> a

S-> b

S^R -> a

S^R -> b

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: $S\hat{}R\to a$ as a grammar rule is not allowed; the left side of a grammar rule must be a symbol, or sometimes a sequence of symbols.  $\hat{}R$ is not a symbol.  it is a notation that means that the thing it is attached to is written backwards.  It should not appear anywhere in your answer.  It appears in the question only to make clear that the strings generated by your grammar should all have three parts: an initial part $w$ that is a string of `a` `b` and `c`, a middle part that is always `c`, and a final part that is the same as the initial part but written backwards.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes what I need to do much clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Build the string from the centre out: $$S\to aSa\mid bSb\mid\ldots$$

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the help.  I see how this works now.

Comment: @Caulibrot: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as Brian's, just a slightly different perspective:

It may help to look at the language in the following way. Instead of
looking for a grammar, look at the structure of the language. That may
suggest a grammar...

It is the smallest language that satisfies: (i) $aca,bcb \in L$ and (ii) if $s \in L$, then so are $asa, bsb$.